# Inconsistent local date formatting between PHP and JS

Tags: javascript, php, date, timezone

I am trying to get consistent local formatting of my timestamp (`2022-09-14T16:58:08.064126Z`) between JavaScript and PHP:

Because the timestamp refers to a date that was within daylight savings (before 30th October this year), the local formatted time for JS comes to `17:58:08`, which makes sense even though I am currently in GMT. However in PHP, I get no adjustment for the time, so the result is `16:58:08`.

How can I format the timestamp in PHP so it has consistent behaviour with JS?

Both my JS env and PHP env are in the same current timezone.

Comment: PHP uses your servers timezone by default and JS the clients timezone which may differ. You can change this using [`date_default_timezone_set`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) or pass the timezone to [`new DateTime($date, $timezone)`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.construct.php).

Comment: @CodeSpirit The timezones between my server and client are the same (Europe/London). JS knows however that for Europe/London, the timezone on `2022-09-14` was +1, and is therefore showing the time for that date as +1 hour. PHP makes no such adjustment

Comment: In your `php.ini` what is in `date.timezone` if its UTC then that does not do Summer time